# how can I list terminals currently in use

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, tty

I want to set the terminal my script is running in as a variable in a bash shell script.
as in tty7, or pts/0 or ttyacm0 etc...

I tried `printenv` , `sudo printenv` and `declare -xp`
but in the list I only saw ssh_term. But I know I have a script running in /dev/tty6
so it isnt listing all the terminals in use, just the current terminal.

is there a simple way to list all the shells in use?

UPDATE:
who -a seems like all the terminals used in the uptime durration. 
the ones that say old are the ones where I know there are other scripts running. 
But what is this +/- business?

```
j0h      - tty6         2014-05-16 07:50  old         9593
LOGIN      tty1         2014-05-15 19:10              1675 id=1
j0h      + tty7         2014-05-15 19:13  old         1936
```

Comment: From `man who`: `who -T` add user's message status as `+`, `-` or `?`. And  _`who -a --all` is same as -b -d --login -p -r -t -T -u_

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the problem correctly you are looking for terminals used by a particular script, if so you can use something like:

```
x=($(ps aux | grep script_name)| awk '{print $7}') #you may have to check which column to filter
```

all terminals used by script would be in array x then you can

```
for i in ${x[*]}
do
echo $i
done
```

for getting individual values

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the current shell that you are using, there is the command

```
tty
```

that print the file name of the terminal connected to standard input  e.g. `/dev/pts/51`

To see  all the shell you can use `w` or `who`.

`who -a` and `who -p` should give you some information more...

Read the man to have a quick view on the possibilities. (You can select the user...)

Update:
Let we say your script is called `MyScript.sh`. If you add as a 1st line

```
#!/bin/bash
```

you change the attribute

```
chmod u+x MyScript.sh
```

and you execute it with `./MyScript.sh` later you can search directly them with

```
pgrep -wal MyScript.sh
```

(It will return the pid of the processes)